# I don't want IE and Chrome to expand my buttons to fit all text

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I am trying to force my button to always have a certain size (in % of the container width). So when the text in the input is longer than the button, Firefox cuts the text off (I like this, although, I would perhaps later look at ways to highlight this to the user somehow), whereas IE and Chrome elongates the button. Disrupting harmony and all that is good.

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/eurythmech/3H2g6/1/

HTML

```
<table class="speed-agenda-button-rows-table">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="speed-agenda-button-row">
            <td class="speed-agenda-button-container">
                <input type="button" data-is-event="1" data-zeroprice="1" data-event-date-id="1329" data-text="881002001" data-price="1658,00" data-link-id="0" class="speed-agenda-button" onclick="if (typeof (onSpeedButtonClick) === 'function') onSpeedButtonClick(this); return false;__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$speedBookingControl$ctl55','')" value="Option A" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$speedBookingControl$ctl55">
            </td>
            <td class="speed-agenda-button-container">
                <input type="button" data-is-event="1" data-zeroprice="1" data-event-date-id="1329" data-text="20100013" data-price="45,00" data-link-id="0" class="speed-agenda-button" onclick="if (typeof (onSpeedButtonClick) === 'function') onSpeedButtonClick(this); return false;__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$speedBookingControl$ctl56','')" value="Option B" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$speedBookingControl$ctl56">
            </td>
            <td class="speed-agenda-button-container">
                <input type="button" data-is-event="1" data-zeroprice="1" data-event-date-id="1329" data-text="20810201" data-price="20,00" data-link-id="0" class="speed-agenda-button" onclick="if (typeof (onSpeedButtonClick) === 'function') onSpeedButtonClick(this); return false;__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$speedBookingControl$ctl57','')" value="The much elongated option C" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$speedBookingControl$ctl57">
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="speed-agenda-button-row">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

css:

```
.speed-agenda-button-rows-table {
    width: 90%;
}
.speed-agenda-button-row {
    width: 100%;
}
.speed-agenda-button-container {
    background-clip: padding-box;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 2px 4px;
    width: 25%;
}
.speed-agenda-button {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #A2A2A2;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #000000;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 10px;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: 0 4px;
    outline: medium none;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add "display:inline-block" property in the following class

```
.speed-agenda-button-container {
background-clip: padding-box;
height: 25px;
padding: 2px 4px;
width: 25%;
display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Will accept your answer. So, Firefox was wrong in rendering the buttons they way I wanted them before this addition?

Comment: MY bad. The Fiddle works in IE. But not in my actual project (I lifted the code straight from it, just changed the button texts. Damnit!)

Comment: Just now i checked in IE10. it is working fine. which version of IE you are checking?

Comment: IE 11. But like I said, it shows the fiddle correctly. But not when I use the exact same code in production. Weird.